# WPF TreeView bound to collection of System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode displays nothing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, treeview

I got a little bit problem I tried to display hierarchical tree of my project files and when I bind my `ObservableCollection` I got nothing and don't know why

Here is my ViewModel:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<TreeNode> Root { get; set; }
private void LoadProject()
{
    var Root = new ObservableCollection<TreeNode>();
    var ParentsNodes = CreateDirectoryNody(new DirectoryInfo(cfg.ProjectPath));
    ParentsNodes.Text = "Source";
    ParentsNodes.Name = "Source";
    Root.Add(ParentsNodes);
}
private TreeNode CreateDirectoryNody(DirectoryInfo projectPath)
{
    var directioryNode = new TreeNode(projectPath.Name);
    foreach (var directory in projectPath.GetDirectories())
        directioryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNody(directory));

    foreach (var file in projectPath.GetFiles())
        directioryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));

    return directioryNode;
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Root}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The `TreeNode` class I'm using is `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`.

Comment: Can you show your XAML?

Comment: @CorentinPane yap

Comment: Could you also show your `TreeNode` class?

Comment: @CorentinPane i using Treenode from windows forms

Comment: why are you mixing Windows Forms with WPF (or what I assume to be WPF)?

Comment: so what do you suggest to do ?

Answer (score 0):

First, **do not mix Windows Forms objects like `TreeNode` with a WPF `TreeView`.**

You should not have to bother about creating `TreeNode` or `TreeViewItem` by yourself. WPF makes it easy for you to build interfaces that are based on your data.

I suggest you create your own `FileTreeNode` class to replace the use of `TreeNode`:

```cs
public class FileTreeNode {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<FileTreeNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Change your `Root` to a collection of `FileTreeNode` instead.

When binding the `TreeView.ItemsSource` to the `Root` collection, you are binding it to a collection of `FileTreeNode` objects. These objects are your data objects that you wish to represent in a hierarchical fashion.

However, when you write `DataType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}"`, you instruct WPF how to draw items of type `TreeViewItem` and these *cannot* be data-templated as they are already `UIElement`. The type you want to target with your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` really is `FileTreeNode`, not the built-in `TreeViewItem`.

Moreover, each of these `FileTreeNode` shall be represented in a *hierarchical* fashion, so you should specify in the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` property the collection to use for each `FileTreeNode` as the collection of children, and that is `Children`, not `Root`.

From there, you should now have:

```xml
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FileTreeNode}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```